# Multiple images, separate nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to upload multiple images.

I know of plupload, elfinder and changing the number of allowed values when creating a content type.
What I want is to upload let's say 25 images, all at once, but they need to be separated nodes when viewing the content of the site. (I don't want all the images in one node.)

I need this so I can use views (slideshow) to make a selection on them...

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create a node for one image!
If you edit the field image in your view, I sure you see a "MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS" fieldset, you only uncheck the "Display all values in the same row" checkbox!

I hope it works.

Regards.